# List of CALayer and float positions

Tags: objective-c, macos, calayer

I need to create a control with a behaviour similar to `UISegmentControl` that shows a list of sublayers into a super layer. 
The number of these sublayers can change and I have to calculate their positions.

Here the problem... if I take a superlayer with a width equal to 31 and I want to place 4 sublayers in it, I should create 4 sublayers each wide 31/4 = 7.75. So the first layer has origin.x = 0, the second has origin.x = 7.75 the third 15.5 and the last 23.25.

Obviously these positions are not valid and they'll produce blurry layers... I can't find a way to round this value being able to fill the whole superlayer and maintaining integer values for width and origin.x, someone has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate all the origins using the exact values, and then round them off to the nearest integral. Then calculate all the widths by simply subtracting the two adjacent origins (or subtracting the total width of your parent from the origin of the final sublayer). This will produce layers that completely cover your parent, with integral coordinates, but some layers will be 1 pixel wider than others.